# Using Resource files in XAML in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, resx

I'm trying to use a resource file in my XAML. For some reason i keep getting the error of not finding the type `Texts`. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

**XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CashRegisterApp.Resources"
             x:Class="CashRegisterApp.Start">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
        <Label Text="{x:Static local:Texts.Start}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**RESX**

[image: resx file]

Solution explorer

[image: solution explorer]

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/localization/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Creating RESX files within Shared projects is known to cause issues. You can see several lengthy posts in Xamarin Forums regarding this ([here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30596/localize-in-shared-project) and [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/86947/xamarin-shared-project-localization) for example).

The easiest solution that will allow you to use the approach you want is to create a new .NET Standard Library of PCL library in your solution, create your RESX files there and set their visibility to `public`. Then you will be able to utilize them using the `x:Static` syntax as expected.

Many developers use an alternative in the form of a custom markup extension like the solution by **ClaudioPereira** in this [forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/86947/xamarin-shared-project-localization). This simplifies the syntax even more.

Finally, for most detailed information on Xamarin.Forms you can refer to the [official documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/localization/).

Comment: Please try to create a whole new RESX file in the library using add new file dialog, set it to public, add a sample string and try to reference it. I suspect your existing RESX doesn't generate the code-behind which is required for it to work

Comment: Seems that it is not working still. i'm still getting an error. i feel like i'm making the smallest of mistakes here...

Comment: I've fixed the current bug but now i got the next one. failed to resolve assembly version=0.0.0.0 culture=neutral publickeytoken=null'

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too and I hope this answer helps people in the future with this issue.

Following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?tabs=vswin#overview) guide taught me how to set up resx files in Xamarin forms. 
Their TranslateExtension allows for referring to the resx file directly from Xaml.

Unfortunately, in its raw form it doesn't pick up a runtime change in locales.
This is fixable by changing their "Localize" class (on the native platforms) to keep a reference of the CultureInfo when changed via the SetLocale method and return it when the GetCurrentCultureInfo method is called.